# Django Rollout to Apache2 server WSGI script load failure

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

This is the first time I have attempted to deploy a Django project.  I am using Raspbian on a Pi3.  The project works with the built in Django test server. The project root (where the manage.py file is) is:

```
/datadisk/powermon/power
```

The virtualenv is found at:

```
/datadisk/powermon/pja
```

The Django settings.py file is at:

```
/datadisk/powermon/power/power
```

I have added the following lines to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess power python-home=/datadisk/powermon/pja
WSGIProcessGroup power
WSGIScriptAlias /power /datadisk/powermon/power/power/wsgi.py
WSGIApplicationGroup $(GLOBAL)
<Directory /datadisk/powermon/power/power>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Apache restarted after the changes.

The WSGI file is the default one that is created by Django.

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "power.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When the browser attempts to access the website it gets a 500 Internal Server Error

Apache reports the following in /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.006487 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0] mod_wsgi (pid=764): Target WSGI script '/datadisk/powermon/power/power/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.007679 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0] mod_wsgi (pid=764): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/datadisk/powermon/power/power/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.008344 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.009152 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "/datadisk/powermon/power/power/wsgi.py", line 24, in <module>
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.009311 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.009905 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "/datadisk/powermon/pja/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.010040 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.010583 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "/datadisk/powermon/pja/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.010719 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.011321 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "/datadisk/powermon/pja/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.011461 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]     self._setup(name)
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.011991 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "/datadisk/powermon/pja/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.012122 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.012677 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "/datadisk/powermon/pja/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.012807 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.013346 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "/datadisk/powermon/pja/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.013482 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.014166 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.014602 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.015010 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.015412 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.015811 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.016194 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.016577 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Tue Oct 17 13:05:25.017090 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 764] [remote 192.168.0.106:0] ImportError: No module named 'power'
```

The reading I have done suggests that the version of WSGI and Python may be incompatible.  I have build the project using python-3.4.2.  I have uninstalled the WSGI for python-2.7 and installed the version for python-3.  When Apache2 restarts the following line appears in the error.log:

```
[Tue Oct 17 13:11:09.523741 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2118] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.4.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Does this line mean that WSGI for Python 3.4.2 has been setup?  If so why is it appearing in the error.log file?  How do I find which version of WSGI is installed?  Is anything else causing this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: It's telling you that it can't find `power`, which is because you haven't done anything either in the Apache configuration or the wsgi file to set the pythonpath (eg by activating the virtualenv).

Comment: The reading I have done suggests that the WSGIDaemonProcess power python-home=/datadisk/powermon/pja line should use the virtualenv setting.  How do I activate the virtualenv from apache2?

Comment: Your code seems to be outside the virtualenv itself, so you'll need to add that directory too.

Comment: The code is outside the virtualenv.  How do I add that directory please?

Comment: This is wrong for a start: ``WSGIApplicationGroup $(GLOBAL)``. Should be ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}``.

Comment: Also likely missing ``python-path=/datadisk/powermon/power/``. This is in addition to ``python-home``.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  I have implemented the suggestions but I still get the same error.  Any other thoughts please?

Comment: Update: on checking again I had spelt the path wrong.  I am now getting a different error that appears to be arising from my code.  Thank you for your help and suggestions.